# Symphony deconstructed by instruments

Tags: instruments

does anyone know if this has been done before? I'm interested in listening to a symphony deconstructed by the instruments. Preferably if I can turn them on or off to listen to the whole piece without 1 specific instrument!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can get quite decent Standard Midi Files of famous classical pieces!

So you can listen to any combination of instruments you like. The better your sound module the better the result will be - provided some decent programming of the file itself...

Comment: It would be helpful to include links to good sources of full-orchestra midi files.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft For example, is [The Mutopia Project](http://www.mutopiaproject.org/) any good?

Comment: @tepples, I'd say yes.